# javamail authenticator not work

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, gssapi, authenticator

here is my configuration to send a mail to my smtp server
but it's not use session authenticator and force me to enter credential from console and when I enter them from console it successfully send mail, which part of my configuration is wrong.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
    //clear it later 

    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable","true");   
    properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms","GSSAPI");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.authorizationid","admin");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.realm","EXAMPLE.COM");

    System.setProperty( "sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.realm", "EXAMPLE.COM");
    System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.kdc", "ipa.example.com"); 


    URL jaasConfigURL = this.getClass().getResource("jaas.conf");
    jaasConfigURL.getFile();
    String jaasConfigFile = jaasConfigURL.getFile();
    System.out.println(jaasConfigFile);
    System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfigFile);
    System.setProperty( "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication("admin", "password");
        }
     });
        session.setDebug(true);
    MimeMessage mime = new SMTPMessage(session);
    mime.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    mime.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
    mime.setSubject("test");
    mime.setText("hello world!");
    Transport.send(mime);
```

and my jaas.conf file

```
krb5_initiate{
com.sun.security.auth.module.krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache="true"
doNotPrompt="true"
debug="true";
};
```

Comment: As described in the [SASL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/sasl/sasl-refguide.html), the GSSAPI SASL implementation doesn't use any SASL callbacks, which is why the JavaMail Authenticator is never used.  The SASL documentation also describes how to use JAAS to login to Kerberos.  I have no experience with that myself.  If that's not working, you might find more help in the [OpenJDK security group](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/security/).

Comment: @BillShannon thank you so much bill